# instance method is returning a hexadecimal instead of a string

Tags: java

I'm practicing learning how to write classes and creating "is" relationships between objects. In the code below, the first class "Person" defines a Person, and then in the second class "MarryDemo", I see whether someone is married, who that spouse is, their address, etc. They even get divorced very shortly thereafter. The code is based on the examples of Jan Skansholm *Java from the Beginning.*

The problem is that I expected the result of the main method in MarryDemo to be "Kris Humphries", "43 New Jersey Jets Street", "null", but instead of the spouse name I got `Person@558ee9d6`, with the spouse's address and the spouse after divorce remaining as I expected them to be.

What does `Person@558ee9d6` signify? Is that the location of the object that is referenced by the name "Kris Humphries"? Why does `Person@558ee9d6` appear instead of the name?

```
//defines a person
public class Person {
    //instance variables
    private String name, address;
    private Person spouse;

    //constructor
    public Person(string n) {
        name = n;
    }

    //instance methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

    public void marry(Person p) {
      spouse = p; 
      p.spouse = this; 
    }

    public Person isMarriedTo() {
        return spouse;
    }

    ... //more methods for returning address, divorcing, etc.

    }
```

---

```
//
public class MarryDemo {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
    String name1 = "Kim Kardashian";
    String name2 = "Kris Humphries";

    Person p1 = new Person(name1);
    Person p2 = new Person(name2);

    p1.marry(p2);
    System.out.println(p1.marriedTo());

    p2.setAddress("43 New Jersey Jets Drive");
    System.out.println(p1.marriedTo().getAddress());

    p1.divorce();
    System.out.println(p1.marriedTo());

    }
}
```

Comment: your     System.out.println(p1.marriedTo());
seems rare, you are trying to print an object, it should be 
    System.out.println(p1.marriedTo().getName());
i guess,.

Comment: In the context of my code snippet, is it preferable to implement/overwrite a toString() method or just to write System.out.println(p1.marriedTo().getName())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `toString()` method (as the default is not suitable).  Most IDE will generate one for you.

> What does Person@558ee9d6 signify?

The class name and identity of the object. See Object.toString() for the code.

> Is that the location of the object that is referenced by the name "Kris Humphries"?

Nothing to do with the name. It is Person.toString() you are calling.

> Why does Person@558ee9d6 appear instead of the name?

Where do you say you want the name to be printed instead?

---

If I replace `string` with `String` and use the IDE to generate a toString, the default is

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", spouse=" + spouse +
            '}';
}
```

This is obviously not suitable as this will go around forever. You can change it to

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", spouse=" + spouse != null ? spouse.getName() : " {none}" +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: ok.  I assumed the default IDE toString would be fine, but in this case there is a circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the `Person` object. You can either overwrite the `toString()` method. e.g

```
public String toString(){
    return this.getName();
}
```

Or, do

```
System.out.println(p1.marriedTo().getName());
```

p.s. `isMarriedTo` is a bad method name because `is` is usually used for methods that return boolean, `getSpouse` would be a much better name

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an object to a String. This (automatically) uses the `toString()` method available in the `Object` class. The result is in the form you described.

If you want to convert it to your own, customized string. You should implement the `toString()` method yourself. For example:

```
public String toString() {
  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to **override** the toString method. The default behaviour is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So what you are seeing is the class name with a hexidecimal representation of the hashcode appended. How is java supposed to know it should print the name property?

You could put this in your person method to display the name:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
}
```